# I am having problems with my horizontal navigation bar

Tags: navigation

I have a header, and the body of my page. The body is 1200px width, with 3 columns. the left column is 20%, middle column is 55% and the right column is 25%. The header of the page is 100% of the page width with position:absolute and top:0px; and left 0px;

I want the navigation bar to line up with the middle column of the body, but I am having problems with it. The left edge of the navigation bar should be directly above the left edge of the middle body column, and the same for the right edges. Either I am having problems with the math of it, or my setup is wrong.

I hope it is clear what I want. Here is my website as it is: http://darkonyx.webatu.com/

Here is my html code:

```
<div id="headerwrapper">
<div id="navbar">
    <ul id="nav">
        <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/roster/roster.html">Roster</a></li>
        <li><a href="/about/about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="/faq/faq.html">FAQs</a></li>
        <li><a href="/contact/contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

with the relevant css styling:

```
#headerwrapper {
position:absolute;
top:0px;
left:0px;
z-index:999;
width:100%;
overflow:hidden;
height:120px;
background:url(img/headerBG.jpg);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 6px 20px #000;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 6px 20px #000;
box-shadow: 0px 6px 20px #000;
/* For IE 8 */
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=4, Direction=135, Color='#000000')";
/* For IE 5.5 - 7 */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=4, Direction=180, Color='#000000');
#navbar{
position:absolute;
top:85px;
left:50%;
width:1200;
margin-left:-600;}
#nav {
width: 100%;
float: left;
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
background-color: #222;}
#nav li {
width:20%;
float: left;}
#nav li a {
display: block;
padding: 8px 15px;
text-decoration: none;
font-weight: bold;
color: #666;
border-right: 1px solid #777;
border-top: 1px solid #777;
border-left: 1px solid #777; }
#nav li a:hover {
color: #000;
background-color: #555;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the following options to the headerwrapper:

```
left:50%;
margin-left:-600px;
```

and change the width to 1200px

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/62849616/Stackoverflow/hor-nav-bar.png

and if you change the width of the inner div to 100% it will look like that:

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/62849616/Stackoverflow/hor-nav-bar2.png

Comment: I like the style of this better than what I had before, so I will use it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have a position: absolute within a class, it's parent should have a position: relative in order for that child div to work well when it comes to positioning.

So

> ```
> 1. Give your #headerwrapper** a position:relative
> 2. Remove top: 100px from #bodycontainer
> 3. Put #navbar into another div, giving this div a margin:0 auto (to be centered) and the same width as the middle body column
> 4. Remove left % from #navbar and remove any position absolutes within it
> ```

Follow that and you'll be good to go!!

Edit: Heres the code

```
<div style="
width: 950px;
margin: 0 auto;
height: 115px;
overflow: hidden;">

<div id="navbar">
<ul id="nav">
<li><a href="">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="/roster/roster.html">Roster</a></li>
<li><a href="/about/about.html">About</a></li>
<li><a href="/faq/faq.html">FAQs</a></li>
<li><a href="/contact/contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Here's the whole stylesheet CSS for a quick copy-paste (take a backup of yours first!!): http://pastebin.com/w5UC8ELF

Comment: can you put it on the live site so that i can see what the problem is?

Comment: Since you're using tables (which isn't such a good idea for a website layout) it's difficult to get divs act like the table. So this is the closest you can get:
For CSS:
http://pastebin.com/QzqqHFp0

For HTML
http://pastebin.com/j0bFCSLx

EDIT-
Instead of width: 35% that i wrote down in the new div (under headerwrapper) you can do width: 707px; which will look much better
Let me know if you have any problems

Comment: So rather that using a table for the body, do I just us a ul?

Comment: No now you can leave it as it is, because re-styling it would be frustrating and difficult. Just copy and paste the new CSS i made for you above and the new html (paste from <body> tag to end </body> tag) http://pastebin.com/AwS98eJb

Comment: I'm not worried about how much work it would be :P so do I use the ul?

Comment: It would be a better idea to just use Divs for the page content, not ul's. Altough it is time consuming since I see that you're using Dreamweaver and look like a casual 'web-maker', and you will have to rebuild your page completely from scratch with divs. Using the code I sent you would be a patch for your current problem with the header.